# How to display default slider in free marketplace theme using Liferay 6.2 CE GA2

Tags: liferay-theme, liferay-6.2

I am using Liferay 6.2 CE GA2. I have downloaded various free Marketplace theme like MADRID Theme but slider is not displaying in theme and how can i use default slider with theme?

Comment: This is highly configurable Liferay theme and you can change the setting by login as admin user and click on edit button select look and feel.

Comment: there is no option of slider or carousal in theme settings in look and feel i have changed color etc but where is slider/carousal option ??

Comment: I have also used biznizz theme but not resolved this problem

Comment: if haven't you seen such option then inside look and file (css section you can define scroll setting like overflow scroll)

Comment: As this is not programming related (thus off-topic for stackoverflow) I'd recommend to direct the question to the theme's author (e.g. on marketplace) or go to the Liferay Theme forums and post there. You may want to try if it behaves differently with the latest GA release - there have been some security updates since your version and you should seriously consider to stay more current than this. GA2 was released 4 1/2 years ago.